golangのビッグデータの表示形式について
golangで、階乗の計算結果の配列(1!~100!)を作成すべく、以下のようなコードを書きました。
package main;
import("fmt"; "math/big"; "reflect";)

var big0 = big.NewInt(int64(0));
var fact_list = [101]big.Int{*big0}; // 結果として、[1]:1,[2]:2,[3]:6,[4];24,...を期待

func main() {
    big1 := big.NewInt(int64(1));
    bign := big.NewInt(int64(1));
    fact := big.NewInt(int64(1));
    fact.Set(bign);
    for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
        fact_list[i].Set(fact)
        bign.Add(bign, big1); fact.Mul(fact, bign);
    }
    fmt.Printf("### big1:%T, %d, fact_list[1]:%T, %d\n",
               reflect.TypeOf(big1), big1, reflect.TypeOf(fact_list[1]), fact_list[1]);
    // 以下のようにして、作成した配列fact_listの中身を確認するつもりだが、
        // 今回の質問には無関係なので、あえてコメントアウト
        //for i := 1; i <= 100; i++ {
    //  fmt.Printf("fact_list[%d]:%d\n", i, fact_list[i]);
    //}
}

この結果は次行の通り。
### big1:*reflect.rtype, 1, fact_list[1]:*reflect.rtype, {%!d(bool=false) [1]}

ご覧のように、データ型は同一なのに、データ表示が異なっているばかりか、後者の表記は解せない！？

回答者に感謝。無事、意図したプログラムができました。今後、goplusも勉強します。（質問者より）


後者の表記は解せない！？

big.Int 型は以下の様な構造体です。なので、{%!d(bool=false) [1] と表示されるのは正しいと言えます。
type Int struct {
    neg bool // sign
    abs nat  // absolute value of the integer
}

ちなみに、gopls による static analysis では、以下の warning message が表示されます。
printf [default]: fmt.Printf format %d has arg fact_list[1] of wrong type math/big.Int

一方、big1 は *big.Int型(ポインタ型)です。なので、以下の様に書き換えます。
    fmt.Printf("### big1:%T, %d, fact_list[1]:%T, %d\n", big1, big1, fact_list[1], &fact_list[1])

// ### big1:*big.Int, 1, fact_list[1]:big.Int, 1

